# Call PL/pgSQL function multiple times with SELECT results

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have a PL/pgSQL function which requires one input parameter which is the primary key of the table on which it works. I call it as follows:

```
select myFunction('0001');
```

It then does some calculations on the data in the row identified by `'0001'` of a particular table and performs an `UPDATE`.

How can I call the function repeatedly for each primary key returned by a query? Something like the following:

```
select myFunction(select ID from theTable);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should call the function as follow:

```
select myfunction(id) from thetable;
```

`id` being the pk of the table.

Comment: As an aside, make sure that any function which is modifying data is `VOLATILE` (the default). http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/xfunc-volatility.html